# How to make the label text changing while changing text field text

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I am making a very simple iphone project but i faced 2 problems problems :

1- i want to make an app the types your name when you type it so i want it to be Immediately typed when i type any letter 
i tied to use `while` but it failed and crashed

2- when i type long name it shows (...) how to make it shows in multiple lines

simply this is my code

```
@synthesize textField,label;

-(IBAction)changeName:(id)sender{

    label.text=textField.text;
    while (label.text != textField.text){
        label.text=textField.text;
    }
    [sender resignFirstResponder];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your view adhere to the [`UITextFieldDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), then implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

And use something like:

```
label.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd question, change the value UILabel's numberOfLines property to 0.

And note that in your solution you are checking for string identity and not equality. So you should be using
`![label.text isEqualToString:textField.text]`

instead of
 `label.text != textField.text;`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this , this will make your label to set as you typed in the TextField.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

UILabel *lbl_YORLabel ;
lbl_YORLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;


CGSize size = [textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


// Now set the Frame size of the label and text.
CGRect _frame = lbl_YORLabel.frame;
_frame.size.height = size.height;
lbl_YORLabel.frame = _frame;


// Set text to the label
lbl_YORLabel.text = textView.text;

return YES;
}
```